# Why ? Object params of function returns undefined JS

Tags: javascript, function, object, constants, return-value

> In this query, i've have small doubt i need to know **WHY?**

We are in #lockdown mean while one of my brother padu asked this question. Below i have sample object, in that there have functions while calling as directly its return **1** but while assign as const and access as function returns **undefined**. Someone have any explainations will real helpful to imporve my knowledge.

```
const apple = 3;
const data = {
  apple: 2,
  bag: {
    apple: 1,
    plastic: function(){
      return this.apple;
    }
  }
}
const plastic = data.bag.plastic;
console.log(plastic())             **//Result - undefined**
console.log(data.bag.plastic())    **//Result - 1**
```

Thanks,

Gopal.R

Comment: `plastic()` has no calling context, so `this` does not refer to `data.bag`

Comment: Simply assign the method to the constant and use the constant.

Comment: `const plastic = data.bag.plastic();
console.log(plastic)`

Comment: @HarryManoharan, that i know,...i just want to know why.. anyway i got it from Certain answer and User863. thanks harry.

Comment: @CertainPerformance, upvoted for your answer, thanks bro. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```js
const apple = 3;
const data = {
  apple: 2,
  bag: {
    apple: 1,
    plastic: function(){
      return this.apple;
    }
  }
}
const plastic = data.bag.plastic.bind(data.bag);
console.log(plastic())           
console.log(data.bag.plastic())
```

Comment: Thanks for you information. answer for why? **plastic() has no calling context, so this does not refer to data.bag. And Solutions was yours.**

https://www.codementor.io/@niladrisekhardutta/how-to-call-apply-and-bind-in-javascript-8i1jca6jp#bind-or-functionprototypebind